# PowerShell script to store passwords fails

Tags: powershell

```
$Computers = get-content C:\temp\computers.txt
$AdminName = Read-Host "Enter your Admin AD username" 
$CredsFile = "C:\pass.txt" 
$FileExists = Test-Path $CredsFile 
if  ($FileExists -eq $false) { 
Write-Host 'Credential file not found. Enter your password:' -ForegroundColor Red 
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $CredsFile 
$password = get-content $CredsFile | convertto-securestring 
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist     $AdminName,$password} 
else  
{Write-Host 'Using your stored credential file' -ForegroundColor Green 
$password = get-content $CredsFile | convertto-securestring 
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName,$password} 
foreach ($computer in $Computers){
if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0)``
{
$network = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $Computer -Filter ipenabled="true"
$ipaddress = $Network.IpAddress[0]
$subnetmask = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
    $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
    $DNSServers  = $Network.DNSServerSearchOrder
$MACAddress = $Network.MACAddress
$OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()    
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value $SubnetMask
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value $DefaultGateway
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DNSServers -Value $DNSServers
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress -Value $MACAddress
    $Outputobj
    $result += $Outputobj
}
}
$result | Export-Csv c:\TEMP\Computerdata.csv
```

Am using the above code to store the password in the text file c:\pass.txt without having to reenter the password mutliple times.

I see the below error while trying this code:

> PS C:\temp> .\passcerds.ps1 Using your stored credential file
>   ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot process argument because the value of
>   argument "input" is invalid. Change the value o the "input" argument
>   and run the operation again. At C:\temp\passcerds.ps1:12 char:64
>   +     $password = get-content $CredsFile | convertto-securestring <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringC
>   mmand
>
> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot
>   process argument because the value of argument " ssword" is null.
>   Change the value of argument "password" to a non-null value." At
>   C:\temp\passcerds.ps1:13 char:23
>   +     $Cred = new-object <<<<  -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist
>   domain\$AdminName,$p sword}
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Is the single quote at the very beginning of the script correct or a typo? because that could really mess things up...  I was able to run the below code, and it works for me:

```
$CredsFile = "C:\pass.txt" 
$FileExists = Test-Path $CredsFile
```

If you were running it from PowerShell and you forgot to set the $CredsFile variable, then you get that error. For ex. the below creates the same error:

```
$FileExists = Test-Path $Nothing
```

Comment: the single quote is a typo. i dint declare $CredsFile variable. how and where exactly i do that.                                              Am new to powershell, appreciate your help if you can point me. thank you.

Comment: thats working for me too. once i run from powershell it works. thank you. this time i see different error

Comment: Try deleting the C:\pass.txt file. If the file is empty, or has some other kind of data, it will not work.

Comment: Try running your PowerShell session as Administrator. Also try changing the path to your $CredsFile to something other than the C: (ex. something like C:\Temp\pass.txt). Trying to write/read stuff to the root of the C: with UAC enabled doesn't necessarily work well. Also, as part of your debugging, try executing the following line: $password = get-content $CredsFile | convertto-securestring  because you can look at what is being stored in the $password variable. From the error message, the variable $password is empty. this is usually because your Get-Content cant access the file or it is empty